# Styling a DataGridRow based on dynamic cell content?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a DataGrid that is populated by an xml response of a web service. Currently, I poll every 5 seconds against the web service to maintain data freshness, as such is essential. Now, this polling can can change the data in one of the columns of the DataGrid, and I would like to style the rows with colors based on the content of a single cell of a row of the DataGrid.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to accomplish this? I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is styleFunction but I think you can only use this on an advancedDataGrid, I don't think the normal dataGrid supports this.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_04.html

You will pass the row object into the function and you can use logic to say whether or not to apply styles.

The only other thing I can think of if you can't use an AdvancedDataGrid is you could probably do it with an item renderer, but that would probably be much more work.

Comment: Looking at labelFunction, I thought there HAD to be some sort of styleFunction. This is exactly what I need.